# Understanding ESIL

Tags: arm, radare2

I cross-compiled a simple program with the `aarch-linux-gnu-gcc` compiler for ARM. So the machine is "ARM aarch64". I want to understand a single instruction and it's realization in ESIL. The opcode of the instruction is: 
`movk x4, 0x40, lsl 16`

The ESIL-string is: `-4294901761,x4,&,4194304,|,x4,=`

Has anybody an idea, why it looks like that? Shouldn't it be a `<<` to "shift left"?

The R2 commands I run are:

```
aa
e asm.syntax = att
e asm.emu = true
pdfj
```

(But i did this in R2pipe)

I am curious about the solution and thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I think the constant has been calculated for the shift as both shift and value are constants. `0x40<<16 =
4194304`

Comment: @sudhackar dammit, you are right. Thank you for your help. Should have seen that. ^^ 
But why would a compiler do something like this? Is the parallel loading to a register and shifting faster than parallel loading by itself?